# error writing to file with ofstream

Tags: c++, io, ofstream

I have a problem with writing number to a file with ofstream. When i write numbers there are characters like this █ instead of numbers. The method i write to the file is:

```
byte _b = 20;
ofstream p_file;
p_file.open("txt.txt", std::ios::app);
p_file << _b;
```

Is there any way to be right, or just use another filewriter method? Thanks.

EDIT:

```
p_file << (int) _b;
```

works fine. Thanks

Comment: "What is `byte`?" means "what is `byte`?". The typename `byte` is **not** built in to the language, and must instead have been defined somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I bet that `byte` is `char` or some variant thereof. In that case you are setting `_b` to the character with code 20, which in ASCII is a control character. The stream output will try to output the character not the number.

You can cast it to another integral type if you want to obtain the number:

```
p_file << static_cast<int>(_b);
```

Answer (score 2):

What is `byte` in your code? I assume it is a typedef of `unsigned char`. Note C++ doesn't have `byte` as data-type.

If so, then `p_file` prints a character whose ASCII value is `20`. That is what you see in the file.

Do this if you want it to print `20` instead :

```
p_file << (int)_b;
```

Or, simply change the data type of `_b`  from `byte` to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
byte _b = 20;
```

to

```
int _b = 20;
```

`byte` is probably typedef to `char` somewhere in your code.